# Splitting multiple PDF files using parallel and mutool

Tags: macos, pdf, terminal, zsh, gnu-parallel

There is a command called `mutool` than enables splitting PDF files vertically with this invocation `mutool poster -y 2`. I would like to run it on every PDF file of a directory.

I tried `parallel 'mutool poster -y 2' ::: *.pdf` , though that doesn't work since I get only one PDF file. I would like to get each file processed, if possible.

How can I achieve that ? If it isn't possible using GNU parallel, is there another way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give `mutool` a name for the output file, otherwise it will use the placeholder name `out.pdf` (which it overwrites):

```
parallel 'mutool poster -y 2 {} {.}_out.pdf' ::: *.pdf
```

Synopsis of mutool poster command: `mutool poster [options] input.pdf [output.pdf]`. After the input filename, the output filename can be given.

`parallel` replaces the curly brackets with input, as described in the documentation:

> If command or the following arguments contain replacement strings (such as {}) every instance will be substituted with the input.

Description of the two replacement forms used above (there are many others):

> **{}** Input line. This replacement string will be replaced by a full line read from the input source.

> **{.}** Input line without extension. This replacement string will be replaced by the input with the extension removed.

Answer (score 1):

You can ask `mutool` to save in a different file:

```
parallel mutool poster -y 2 {} {.}_poster.pdf ::: *.pdf
```